# Display VlcJ in JavaFX using SwingNode

Tags: java, swing, javafx-8, vlcj

FXMLController initialize method:

```
@FXML
private VBox vbContainer;
MediaPlayerVLC m_mediaPlayer;

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();

        m_mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayerVLC();
        createAndSetSwingContent(swingNode, m_mediaPlayer);

        vbContainer.getChildren().add(0, swingNode);
    }
```

And createAndSetSwingContent():

```
private void createAndSetSwingContent(final SwingNode swingNode, JComponent jComponent) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swingNode.setContent(jComponent);
            }
        });
    }
```

MediaPlayerVLC class:

```
package javafxswing;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;

public class MediaPlayerVLC extends JPanel {

    private final EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;

    public MediaPlayerVLC() {

        setSize(350, 320);
        setVisible(true);        
        mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
        mediaPlayerComponent.setSize(350, 320);
        add(mediaPlayerComponent);
    }

    public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
        return mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer();
    }
}
```

And I play the media by clicking a button, in FXMLController:

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
     System.out.println("You clicked me!");
     m_currentVideo = "video.mov";
     m_mediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(m_currentVideo);
}
```

Now, the problem: The video starts to play but I can see no image. I say it starts to play because I can hear the audio. What am I doing wrong?

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, it won't work this way.

From the Javdoc for `SwingNode` here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html

It states, in part:

> The hierarchy of components contained in the JComponent instance should not contain any heavyweight components, otherwise SwingNode may fail to paint it.

In the case of vlcj, the `EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent` extends `Panel`, a heavyweight AWT component.

To use with vlcj with JavaFX you will likely have to render the video data directly yourself. This is what vlcj's so-called `DirectMediaPlayerComponent` is for. The essence of this approach is that the `DirectMediaPlayerComponent` receives each frame of video data to render, and you would then render this yourself using a `PixelWriter` or some other means that you come up with.

There is a vlcj-javafx project here https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-javafx, and this approach works up to Java7. It does not work with Java8 due to wrong threading, documented here: https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-javafx/issues/3

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've already tried that approach and even using a WritableImage instead of Canvas I couldn't obtain the rendering performance of the vlcj in Swing version.

Comment: For best performance you need the heavyweight component and to have VLC render your video. Unfortunately, it simply won't work inside a SwingNode and there's nothing to be done about it frankly.

Comment: This answer is a bit out of date, the recommended approach now is to use the new PixelBuffer approach with modern versions of vlcj and JavaFX