# Add a VLCJ media player to a canvas in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, vlcj

I am learning how to add a VLCJ player to my application written with javaFX and FXML  I read in other questions that i had to add to a canvas so i created a canvas in my FXML under an anchorpane.

```
 <Canvas fx:id="mediaPlayerCanvas" height="174.0" layoutX="-4.0" layoutY="-2.0" width="595.0" />
```

then i initialised it in my application.java

```
@FXML
 public void mediaPlayerCanvas()
{
 mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
}
```

and finally i created a MediaPlayer.java that includes this

```
package Lasercontroller;


import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.RootPaneContainer;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.discovery.NativeDiscovery;

public class MediaPlayer {
private final Canvas canvas;

private final EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent;

public synchronized void start(final String[] args) {
    new NativeDiscovery().discover();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new MediaPlayer();
        }
    });
}

public MediaPlayer() {
    canvas = new Canvas();
    //canvasl.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 400);


    String mediaLocation = "rtsp://192.168.1.175/stream1";
    canvas.setVisible(true);
    mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent();
    //panel.setContentPane(mediaPlayerComponent);

    mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(mediaLocation);

}


}
```

When i run my application i get an exception `The video surface component must be displayable`

What have i done wrong? i have read lots of other question but i dont understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent` inherits from `java.awt.Panel` - it's an AWT component, completely unrelated with JavaFX. It's designed to be used with AWT or Swing.

At fist glance, one solution would seem to be to use a `javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode` to [embed some Swing content](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/embed_swing/jfxpub-embed_swing.htm) inside your JavaFX application. However, this won't work, because `EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent` is a heavyweight component, and the javadoc for `SwingNode` states : "The hierarchy of components contained in the JComponent instance should not contain any heavyweight components, otherwise SwingNode may fail to paint it" (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24803535/3801695)).

So, as far as I know, tehre is no way to use `EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent` in javaFX.

One possible solution is to use vlcj's `DirectMediaPlayerComponent`, and implement yourself the code to write each frame on a JavaFX Canvas. There is a relevant example [on github](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-javafx). Note that this will not be as efficient (in terms of performances) as an `EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I spend a few hours trying to implement the `DirectMediaPlayerComponent` but its above me so I opted for a new swing frame to play the media instead of embedding it.